# Reference request: arithmetical implications of an ambient Galois extension

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

This is a cross-post of a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4522410) I asked on StackExchange. See there for further details.

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension of algebraic number fields of finite degree over $\mathbb{Q}$, with group $G$. Let $E$ and $F$ be intermediate fields, with stabilizer subgroups $H$ and $I$, respectively. For $\sigma$ $\in$ $G$, put $\mathfrak{e}_{\sigma,L}$ $=$ $\sum_{\alpha \in \mathfrak{O}_{L}} (\alpha - \sigma(\alpha)) \mathfrak{O}_L$. (Here, $\mathfrak{O}_X$ is the ring of integers of the field $X$.)

Then, if  $\mathfrak{f}$ denotes the conductor $(\mathfrak{O}_E \mathfrak{O}_F : \mathfrak{O}_{EF})$, one has $\mathfrak{f} \cdot \mathfrak{O}_L$ $=$ $\prod \mathfrak{e}_{\sigma,L}$ where $\sigma$ runs over the set $HI-(H\cup I)$. This is stated in the 1980 paper "On the integer ring of the compositum of algebraic number fields" by Toshitaka Kataoka, [this DOI](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0027763000018626), top of page 30. Kataoka remarks that this follows from the fundamental properties of "Elements", as he calls the ideals $\mathfrak{e}_\sigma$. My question:

> What is a good reference that describes the general properties of the ideals $\mathfrak{e}_{\sigma}$?

**Edit:** I have included a proof on the StackExchange side. References still welcome.